# Try to install magento migration tool fails

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, composer, centos

When i try to install the migration tool from magento i get errors. ( see image )

Hope some one can help me out.

[image]

Now i have it installed and frond end and backend gives error :

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

If i check the log i see this.
[image]

I have used bin/magento setup:upgrade and php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Nothing helped.

Comment: Which magento version are you used?

Comment: the newest from composer so 2.1.7

Comment: Use this command : composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.1.7

Comment: Same problem when i use that command

Comment: run first :  composer update

Comment: That did the trick but now i have other problem, i will post the image

Comment: run command : php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Thanks but i allready did that. Did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

This issue resolved in this ticket [composer error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249620/the-openssl-extension-is-required-for-ssl-tls-protection)

please check it. 
disable tls in composer using the below command

```
composer config -g -- disable-tls true
```

or

```
nano ~/.composer/config.json ...

{
    "config": {
        "disable-tls": true,
        "secure-http": false
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is work please let me know

Comment: This dont work. Check my edit above.

Comment: first run composer update

Comment: i allready did that. It's already done because when i do it now it says "nothing to update"

Comment: what is the current error through is upgrade issue am i correct?

Comment: See my original post. i edit it.